# A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProjectNameI'

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I run my Project, the Error bellow always appear, And I have tested all of the solutions that I found in the Internet, but its not solved my problem.
This project I received for someone to run in my PC, for contributing in development, and I also a beginner in React Native.

The errors are:

r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProjectName'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> Required by:
> project : > project :gradle-plugin

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yvv2.png)

Thanks in advance for someone who will help me in this case!
crs...